# How to get the first line of a RSS feed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rss

Okay so I want to get the very first entry in a RSS feed using javascript.
Here's my actual code:

```
$.get('http://www.pebkac.fr/feed/rss/', function(data) {
var $xml = $(data);
$xml.find("item").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        item = { title: $this.find("title").text() };


pbknbr = item.title.substr(8,4);
console.log(pbknbr);
    });
});
```

This code show me a specific part of the titles in that feed, which is what I want, except the fact that I only want the first title. (it actually show me the 30 last entries)
And I don't know how to do that. Any help ?
Thanks

Comment: Why use an `each()` loop if you don't want all of the items?

Comment: Idk, I'm kind of a noob in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this snippet is quite off, I would have refactor it but to get your job done just add .first()

```
$xml.find("item").first().each(function()
```

Comment: Works as I expected. Thanks!